# An inequality for a concave function $f(x)=x^{p/2}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequalities

Assume that $p\in(1,2]$, $a,b\ge 1$, $b\le -\frac{1}{2} \left(\cos\frac{\pi }{p}+\sec\frac{\pi }{p}\right)$,   and $t\in[0,\pi]$. How to prove this inequality $$\left(\frac{a+\cos t}{b+\cos\frac{\pi }{p}}\right)^{p/2}\geq \left(\frac{a+\left(a b-\sqrt{a^2-1} \sqrt{b^2-1}\right) \cos\frac{\pi }{p}}{b+\cos\frac{\pi }{p}}\right)^{p/2}+\frac{\cos\frac{p t}{2} \sin\frac{\pi }{p}}{b+\cos\frac{\pi }{p}},$$

Answer (score 5):

*This is an answer to the question as it was originally formulated by the OP.*

---

For $p=1$, $a=1$, $b=2$ the left-hand-side equals $\sqrt{1+\cos t}$, but the right-hand-side equals $i$, so the inequality does not hold.

Comment: The formulation is changed in order to have real numbers in both side.

Comment: please don't do that, change the question after it has been answered, we try to avoid "moving targets".